# Problems with Ring in cosmos; invalid namespace

Tags: c#, ring, cosmos

I have done everything that the official COSMOS website told me to add; all the references, cosmos.common, etc.
It asked me to add:

```
using Cosmos.Common;
[assembly: Ring(Ring.System)]
```

So of course I split them into two parts, with the using part with all the others, and the assembly in the assemblies.
My current code for AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Cosmos.Common.Extensions;
using Cosmos.Common;
using Cosmos.Core;
using Cosmos.Debug;
using Cosmos.System;
using Cosmos.Common.Extensions;
using Cosmos.Hardware.BlockDevice;
using Cosmos.Hardware.Drivers.PCI.Network;




// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: Ring(Ring.Hardware)] 
// This ^^^ is broken, has a red line under the first "ring" 
// "The type or namespace name 'Ring' could not be found. (Are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Package Name")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Company")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Package Name")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
[assembly: CLSCompliant(false)]
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US")]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Revision and Build Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Comment: Are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?

Comment: No. According to the website, I only needed the common for it to work. Just to be sure, i added every other assembly reference possible.

Comment: Did you reference the cosmos assembly?  NOTE: Don't confuse `using` directives with assembly references.  Do you know the difference?

Comment: The code for Cosmos.Common has to reside somewhere.  When you ran install-VS2015.bat, did it produce any artifacts, like a Cosmos.DLL assembly?

Comment: Yes it did, it did in fact produce a cosmos.dll

Comment: Did you reference this DLL in your project  you're trying to compile?

Comment: Download JustDecompile from the Telerik website, and use it to verify that Cosmos.DLL contains a class called RingAttribute in the Cosmos.Common namespace.  See also https://github.com/CosmosOS/Cosmos/blob/master/source/Cosmos.Common/RingAttribute.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also got this error. In the COSMOS official tutorial it says we want to add all dlls in Kernel directory of COSMOS User Kit as reference. Right click the references in hardware project and click add references. Then click browse and goto C:/Program Files/Cosmos User Kit/Kernel/ then select all dlls and add to reference it would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your kernel script in the same project or solution, any attempt to invoke system or hardware ring will be blocked when the il2cpu compiler is started.